# Create windows AD login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I have a domain with the name `test.com` and I have a simple query to add an account from this domain to the SQL Server Logins:

```
CREATE LOGIN [test.com\MyUser] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DB];
```

But for some reason it fails with the error `Windows NT user or group 'test.com\MyUser' not found. Check the name again.`.

When I specify the domain name without '.com' it works:

```
CREATE LOGIN [test\MyUser] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DB];
```

What is the reason and how to make it working for both queries?

Comment: its the same in my domain too. domain\user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, read this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> "When you are creating logins that are mapped from a Windows domain
> account, you must use the pre-Windows 2000 user logon name in the
> format domain_Name\login_name"

And "domainName" refers to Windows domain, which is not in "test.com" format.

Comment: It definitely makes sense, I read through the article a few times before but I never paid enough attention to the statement you've pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the pre-Windows 2000 domain name may not be the same as the newer one without `.com`

Comment: @Carlos When you said 'Windows domain' did you mean NetBIOS domain name? Are these the same?

Comment: @managerger Windows domain is your active directory domain. Anyway I am not an expert on domains, but although NetBIOS domain use to be the same as Windows domain, I think they can be different in some scenarios. Take a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/disjoint-namespace-scenarios-exchange-2013-help